# Does the difference in the color of the Schneider-Kreuznach logo on these large-format lenses indicate any other differences?

Tags: lens, large-format

What is the difference between the two lenses pictured below? They are both same brand, same focal length, etc.... The only thing is the color of the Schneider font on them is different. Is one of them older production, perhaps? Are there any other differences?

[image]

and this one:

[image]

Comment: are they fisheye lenses or lens adapters?

Comment: These are kind of Portrait lenses for Large Format cameras ...

Comment: Aside from the color used to brand the lenses, why do you believe that there's a difference at all?

Answer (score 2):

Did some research on other forums, looks like the second one in the pictures above is newer. They also said higher serial number is also another way to tell.